# Using pandas.read_csv() is conflicting with csv.reader() - ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, io

I'm parsing a csv file, that was sent via POST `FormData()`, and then converting it to JSON. The problem appears when I used a package to validate the csv before pass through pandas. The validator function does her job and then, the normal reading with pandas gives the error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.form
        data_header = json.loads(content.get('JSON'))
        filename = data_header['data'][0]['name']
        
        # Here! starts the problem
        # validator = validCSV(validator={'header': ["id","type","name","subtype","tag","block","latitude","longitude","height","max_alt","min_alt","power","tia","fwl"]})
        # print(validator.verify_header(request.files[filename]))
        # then pseudo-code: if returned false, will abort(404)
        
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(request.files[filename], dtype='object')
            dictObj = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

If we follow the issue to inside of this package, this is what we will see:

```py
def verify_header(self, inputfile):
        with TextIOWrapper(inputfile, encoding="utf-8") as wrapper:
            header = next(csv.reader(wrapper))
```

It seems when the file is opened and closed by `TextIOWrapper`, pandas is no longer allowed to open the file using the `read_csv()`. But makying a copy of the file seems a waste for only read a header and i like the idea of using the `csv.reader()` because showed in other examples more efficiency reading a csv file than pandas.

what can be done to prevent I/O Error after another package had opened the file? Or a simple and efficient way to validate the csv without using a heavy pandas

Comment: It may be faster to verify csv using csv.reader() than pandas, but if you're going to load with pandas anyway, does pre-filtering with csv.reader really speed things up? Do you find errors faster this way? Does the speed of detecting errors really matter for your use case? Does csv.reader do checks that pandas doesn't?

If you really need to pre-check with csv reader, you're going to have to cache the file somehow. Maybe a buffered IO reader? 

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#buffered-streams

Comment: In  this case, the time will be important since the api server will be validating multiple upload requests at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was seek() the pointer to beginning of the file after read the first line. The process of reading is almost the same as what pandas do. The only apparently advantage is that it does not depend on importing/installing pandas.

```py
wrapper = StringIO(inputfile.readline().decode('utf-8'))
        header = next(csv.reader(wrapper,  delimiter=','))
        inputfile.seek(0,0)
```